# Is there a simpler way to code the following requirement and compress the code?

Tags: android

I have made a custom bottom bar. It has got five images. On selecting a particular image a fragment will open and the selected image will turn blue. The rest will remain black.
 So what I am doing now is

> img1,img2,img3,img4,img5

So I set click listener to it and doing it like

```
     @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.img1:
// Set background image as blue to img1 and set //black for others
                    break;
                case R.id.img2:
// Set background image as blue to img2 and set //black for others including the previous one
                    break;
                case R.id.img3:
                    break;
                case R.id.img4:
                    break;
                case R.id.img5:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So I am doing the repetitive steps again and again . can I compress this code to something shorter , like storing the previous image in a view and coloring the current one ?? In nutshell what is the best way to compress this code ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background color of all the images to black BEFORE the `try` sentence, and then set only the selcted image's background to blue:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //Set black background for all the imags
    try {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.img1:
                // Set background image as blue to img1 for others
                break;
```

Comment: I'd remove the `switch` at all, and used the ID to set the blue color directly without `switch`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko this would work if only these five things are supposed to be clicked, but this is a small part of large activity operations, so there would be many other kind of clicks as well.

Comment: I am kind of trying the same, but something is not working, I have used two image views in a layout so kind of not working properly, I am making it visible and invisible.lokks like I may need to set it programatically

Comment: @Pritish, then just don't set every object's click listener to `this`. Set different click listeners, and you won't get all that mess.